# Im getting a makefile error file(dot)o no such file or directory. Is there any way to fix this?

Tags: gcc, makefile

im getting this error when i try to compile my C program i get in the teminal:

```
rm -rf *.o *.gch deq_tester simple_testerv2
gcc -Werror -Wall -g -c simple_testerv2.c deq.h
gcc -Werror -Wall -g -c deq_tester.c deq.h
gcc -Werror -Wall -g -o simple_testerv2 simple_testerv2.o deq.o
gcc: error: deq.o: No such file or directory
makefile:10: recipe for target 'simple_testerv2' failed
make: *** [simple_testerv2] Error 1
```

here's my makefile:

```
all: simple_testerv2 deq_tester

CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Werror -Wall -g

deq_tester: deq_tester.o deq.o
   $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o deq_tester deq_tester.o deq.o

simple_testerv2: simple_testerv2.o deq_tester.o 
   $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o simple_testerv2 simple_testerv2.o deq.o

deq_tester.o:
   $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c deq_tester.c deq.h

simple_testerv2.o:
   $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c simple_testerv2.c deq.h

deq.o:
   $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c deq.c deq.h

clean:
   rm -rf *.o*.gch deq_tester simple_testerv2
```

I have put my makefile in the same directory with my files c files and header files but everytime i compile it gives me this error. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You link `simple_testerv2` with `dew.o` but don’t tell `make` that you’re going to do so.  Add a dependency `dew.o` there too.

Comment: Ahh ok it works now. Thanks for you help :)

Comment: Apologies for the `deq.o` --> `dew.o` repeated typo.  I put it down to iPhone spell-mangler and inadequate caffeination.

Comment: Note that your compilation lines should not try compiling `deq.h`.  The file will be included when the source file is compiled.  (Hence: change `$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c deq.c deq.h` to `$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c deq.c`, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sup>*Converting comments into an answer.*</sup>

You link `simple_testerv2` with `deq.o` but don’t tell `make` that you’re going to do so. Add a dependency `deq.o` there too (and remove the unnecessary dependency on `deq_tester.o`).

```
simple_testerv2: simple_testerv2.o deq.o 
   $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o simple_testerv2 simple_testerv2.o deq.o
```

Consider whether macros can help more:

```
PROG2 = simple_testerv2
OBJ2  = simple_testerv2.o deq.o

${PROG2}: ${OBJ2}
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -o $@ ${OBJ2}
```

You could add `${PROG2}` to the list of programs that are built by your `all` target (provided you move the `all` target after the macro is defined).

Note that your compilation lines should not try compiling `deq.h`. The file will be included when the source file is compiled. (Hence: change `$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c deq.c deq.h` to `$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c deq.c`, etc.)  Indeed, you don't really need to specify the compile line at all; `make` knows how to convert a `.c` file into a `.o` file.  So you could write:

```
deq_tester.o: deq.h
deq.o: deq.h
simple_testerv2.o: deq.h
```

That tells `make` that the files include the header (so if the header changes, the object files need to be recompiled).  `Make` has built-in rules that tell it to build `xyz.o` from `xyz.c` so you don't need to tell it about that dependency (though there's no harm done if you do add the source file dependency).

Comment: Made the changes and removed the .h files and everything is much easier to read now :) . One more question, what does the $@ mean and is there any difference from using (CC) or {CC} for example?

Comment: There’s no difference between `${CC}` and `$(CC)`.  I learned the brace notation so I use it. Parentheses is more usual.  Consistency is most important.

Comment: The `$@` macro is a special built-in macro that gives the name of the target being built.  There are a number of other built-in macros for vaguely similar purposes.  They’re covered in manuals.  This is the most useful one.

Comment: Ahh ok that clears it all now. Thanks for your help :)